# decrease/increase between date in mysql or oracle SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I've problem in query mysql
I want to find hour per date between 2 date divided by day
for example,

---

I have startdate **14/12/2014 09:00:00AM** , and enddate **17/12/2014 03:30:00AM**

I want to result like this

1. 14/12/2014  -  15 hour
2. 15/12/1014  -  24 hour
3. 16/12/2014  -  24 hour
4. 17/12/2014  -  3,5 hour

---

Is that possible in a MySQL or Oracle SQL query?

Comment: Check out datediff and date_sub

Comment: This isn't really an SQL problem

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) or Oracle [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function to calculate difference between two value fields of Datetime type (2nd and 3rd parameters). 1st parameter passed is your selected measurement to count the difference. This could be HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, DAY etc.

```
SELECT 
  `startdate` AS `date`, 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    HOUR, 
    `startdate`, 
    `enddate`) AS `hours_delta`
FROM my_table
```

The result would be:

> ___date_______hours_delta____
>
> 14/12/2014________66________
>
> 15/12/1014________..._________

Comment: That's my fault. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Zon
___________
I was using Toad for Oracle to execute those query_____
but TIMESTAMPDIFF is invalid identifier____
is there any replacement for timestampdiff in oracle sql?_____
_____
this is my query
_____
_____
SELECT to_date(A.TGL_SLS_STT, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS end_date, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, to_date(A.TGL_MUL_STT,'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date(A.TGL_SLS_STT, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) AS hours
FROM STG_STT_MESIN_PMBKT_2014 A

Comment: Use EXTRACT(DAY from (first_date - second_date)). See details at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the query for oracle sql... 
THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

---

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE (START_DATE + COLUMN_VALUE - 1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS THE_DATE,
  CASE
    WHEN TO_DATE (START_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE (END_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      THEN (END_DATE - START_DATE)*24
    WHEN (START_DATE + COLUMN_VALUE - 1) = START_DATE
      THEN (23 - TO_CHAR (START_DATE, 'HH24')) + ((60 - TO_CHAR (START_DATE, 'MI'))/60) + ((360 - TO_CHAR (START_DATE, 'SS'))/360)
    WHEN TO_DATE (START_DATE + COLUMN_VALUE - 1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <> TO_DATE (END_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      THEN 24
    ELSE TO_CHAR (END_DATE, 'HH24') + 
         (TO_CHAR (END_DATE, 'MI')/60) + 
         (TO_CHAR (END_DATE, 'SS')/360) END
FROM MY_TABLE,
     TABLE( CAST( MULTISET (
       SELECT
         LEVEL L
       FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= END_DATE - START_DATE + 1) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST))
```

Comment: No. Use EXTRACT(DAY from (first_date - second_date)).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8633/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE ( ID, START_DATE, END_DATE ) AS
          SELECT 1, TO_DATE( '14/12/2014 09:00:00AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM'), TO_DATE( '17/12/2014 03:30:00AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TO_DATE( '20/12/2014 09:00:00AM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM'), TO_DATE( '20/12/2014 03:30:00PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SSAM') FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Differences AS (
  SELECT ID,
         TRUNC( START_DATE ) AS Day,
         LEAST(
           TRUNC( START_DATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
           END_DATE
         ) - START_DATE AS Diff
  FROM   MY_TABLE
  UNION
  SELECT ID,
         COLUMN_VALUE,
         CASE WHEN COLUMN_VALUE < TRUNC( END_DATE )
              THEN 1
              ELSE END_DATE - COLUMN_VALUE
              END
  FROM   MY_TABLE,
         TABLE( CAST( MULTISET (
           SELECT TRUNC( START_DATE ) + LEVEL
           FROM   DUAL
           WHERE  TRUNC( START_DATE ) + LEVEL <= TRUNC( END_DATE )
           CONNECT BY
                  TRUNC( START_DATE ) + LEVEL <= TRUNC( END_DATE )
         ) AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST ) )
)
SELECT ID,
       TO_CHAR( Day, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS Day,
       TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( Diff * 24 ), '99D90' )
         || ' hour ' AS Hours
FROM   DIFFERENCES
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8633/13/0)**:

```
| ID |        DAY |        HOURS |
|----|------------|--------------|
|  1 | 2014-12-14 |  15.00 hour  |
|  1 | 2014-12-15 |  24.00 hour  |
|  1 | 2014-12-16 |  24.00 hour  |
|  1 | 2014-12-17 |   3.50 hour  |
|  2 | 2014-12-20 |   6.50 hour  |
```